# Consulta de SQL para que me muestre solamente los usuarios que tienen X evento repetido N veces

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy jugando con SQL y tratando de ir haciendo algunas consultas, pero no puedo con esto, primero les voy a poner un ejemplo de una tabla (que se me ocurrió ahora) llamada, en este caso, MiTabla:

| USUARIOS | BEBIDAS |
| --- | --- |
| Carlos | Coca |
| Carlos | Manaos |
| Carlos | Coca |
| Carlos | Coca |
| Maria | Coca |
| Maria | Coca |
| Marcelo | Tinto |
| Marcelo | Coca |
| Etc | Etc |

Entonces, yo quiero realizar una consulta en donde me aparezcan solamente los usuarios (suponiendo que cada nombre de usuario es único) que tienen en su registro, mas de 1 bebida "coca" solicitada y la cantidad de veces que tienen esa bebida y bueno, también el nombre de la bebida, en este caso el resultado que me gustaría tener sería:

| Usuarios | Bebidas | Repetición |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carlos | Coca | 3 |
| Maria | Coca | 2 |

O simplemente

| Usuarios | Repetición |
| --- | --- |
| Carlos | 3 |
| Carlos | 2 |

Lo intenté de muchas maneras, las cuales me tiraba error o no hacía lo que queria (no se si vale la pena copiarlo, de ser necesario lo hago jajaja), pero quería saber de que forma/s ustedes harían esta consulta, ya que supongo que hay varias maneras y bueno, siempre es bueno ir obteniendo muchos métodos para hacerlo.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Agrego el código con el que lo intenté:

```
select *
from MiTabla
where Usuarios in (select Usuarios from MiTabla group by Usuarios having count(*)>1 order by Usuarios)
and Bebidas='Coca'
```

Comment: Agregar el código de lo que has intentado. de lo contrario cerraran tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te entendí bien, lo resuelves con un filtro y un `group by` +  `having`:

```
select Usuarios,
       Bebidas,
       count(*) as 'Repetición'
       from MiTabla 
       where Bebidas= 'Coca'
       group by Usuarios,
                Bebidas
       having count(*) > 1 
       order by Usuarios
```

Comment: Creo que el `WHERE` está de más. Pareciera necesario, pero es solo resultado del `GROUP BY` + `HAVING`.

Comment: Buenas, me funcionó perfecto esta respuesta, después voy a ver bien en que meti la mata (o que quise hacer) cuando escribí el código que puse en mi pregunta jajaja. Igualmente, espero que este permitido, voy a dejar un rato mas esta pregunta como "no resuelta", a ver si alguien mas tira otra respuesta con otra forma para hacer esto. Igual obviamente, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Debes agrupar los dos campos nombre y bebida y asi podras sacar el contador

```
select * from (
SELECT Usuarios,Bebidas,count(Bebidas)as cantidad
FROM MiTabla group by Usuarios,Bebidas) as other where cantidad >1 and Bebidas='Coca';
```

Comment: Puse tu código (obviamente cambiando los nombres de las columnas por los de la tabla con la que estoy practicando) y me tira "SQL compilation error: Objetct 'EVENT' does not exist or not authorized

Aclaración: EVENT en mi tabla sería como se llama la columna de "Bebidas" en este ejmplo

Comment: ponla entre comillas dobles ya que tu nombre de tabla puede ser reservada  "EVENT"

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta. Lo intenté, sigue el mismo error.
 No se si sirve de algo, pero puedo realizar consultas más basicas como:
...... where EVENT='algo' y me lo mustra correctamente, sin necesidad de ponerle ninguna "" o '' a EVENT

Comment: Esta consulta la realice en mi local creando las tablas y funciona, es decir la logica te va funcionar, debe ser otro tu problema, actualice la respuesta con los nombre de tu  tabla. La respuesta de Patricio te Sirvió? esta marcada como respuesta correcta.

Comment: Intenta solo asi SELECT Usuarios,Bebidas,count(Bebidas)as cantidad
FROM MiTabla group by Usuarios,Bebidas

Comment: Ahí probé la respuesta de arriba y efectivamente funcionó... raro. Ahora me tengo que ir pero después voy a probar esto último que dijiste, tampoco entiendo por que lo que me pasaste me tira ese error con EVENT, igual desde ya, gracias!